# Teradata - report for top "stats hoggers"

Tags: sql, database, report, teradata, sql-tuning

Trying to compile a "statistics Hoggers" report . All those users who hogged away CPU running statistics  
 On what "table.cols" ( or col1,col2 etc) , did they run stats and when they ran it.

I wrote the below report but I can see its far from real

- It does not "Split" the CPU on a given query by some proportion of weights to table. So if in a stats operation - the most expensive CPU was on FACT.BILLION_DOLLAR table but there was also a DIMENSION.DWARF table , DIMENSION.DWARF will spuriously show up on the chart -which makes the report misleading. 
   I am also trying to compile another report where I want the TOP CPU by TABLE. Its not "Strictly" poss because the CPU is for a query not object but inside a query I want to "split" the CPU in proportion ( I guess the count(*) would be 1 criteria ). So HOW do I get this done
- It "pulls over the wrong guy"- the username against running the stats operation shows up incorrectly. Our production ID that runs stats is SWPRDUSR but the top stats user shows up as SYSPRDUSR who is  the system wide prod. user and he really does'nt mess with our stuff- so I know something is amiss here.

   Here's what I am running 
  I am running this report not system wide BUT only for my  My database , cascaded

  `sel 
  a.username,
  s.ObjectTableName,
  s.objectdatabasename,
  --s.ObjectColumnName,
  cast ( s.CollectTimeStamp  as date ) ,
  CAST( SUM((((a.AmpCPUTime(DEC(18,3)))+
  ZEROIFNULL(a.ParserCPUTime)) )) AS DECIMAL(18,3)) as Total_CPU 
  from

  DBC.DBQLogtbl  a join DBC.DBQLoBJTBL   s 
  on  (  s.ProcID    = a.ProcID
   and   cast ( s.CollectTimeStamp  as date )  = cast ( a.CollectTimeStamp as date ) )
  where    objectdatabasename in  ( 
  sel child

  from     dbc.children 
  where   parent ='FINDB'

  group by     1 )
  and ObjectType='tab'
  and    statementType='collect statistics' 
  group by 1,2,3,4
  UNION ALL
  sel 
  a.username,
  s.ObjectTableName,
  s.objectdatabasename,
  s.Logdate,
  --s.ObjectColumnName,
  CAST( SUM((((a.AmpCPUTime(DEC(18,3)))+
  ZEROIFNULL(a.ParserCPUTime)) )) AS DECIMAL(18,3)) as Total_CPU 
  from

  PDCRinfo.DBQLogtbl  a join PDCRinfo.dbqlobjtbl_hst   s
   on  (  s.queryID     = a.queryID
   and     s.Logdate   =  a.Logdate )

  where    objectdatabasename in  ( 
  sel child

  from     dbc.children 
  where   parent ='FINDB'

  group by     1 )
  and ObjectType='tab'
  and    statementType='collect statistics' 
  group by 1,2,3,4
  order  by 5 desc , 3 asc, 2 asc, 1 asc
  ;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the 1st Select there's a missing join condition: `s.queryID     = a.queryID`

`Collect Stats` is always single table, no need to split CPU.

Comment: You are right. TY ... What a bad miss. I need new pair of glasses..... or whatever is behind those...or whatever is behind  ( behind those )... I saw the PI as Logdate and ProcID on the PI ( not sure why QueryID was'nt there . If queryID is there it'd be a PI - PI join with the query ID giving better distribution and part of the join )..and grabbed those...assuming there's nothing beyond those. OBJECT , LOG and SQL all 3 tables have QueryID in there. Why not keep it in the PI . Thanks for the info Dieter

Comment: @user1874594: The PI of the DBQL tables in dbc is only for writing the cached data efficiently as a single data block. That's why the data must be moved to a history table daily, otherwise all joins on QueryId perform really bad.

Comment: Hi Dieter. On a corollary to that - if I need to know tables with Max CPU Hits . How do I go about getting these - there  multiple tables per Query

Comment: There's no way to split CPU between tables.

Comment: I'm thinking of using this kind of logic. If the stats  table has a row count value that is less than 5 days old... go ahead and pick the value or else do a count (*) .  Then use a formula that does a CPU for a queryid per row per table. So for a query. If there are 3 facts and 5 dimensions ..... and there is a high CPU... Facts  get a higher wt. It is not picture perfect.... but it helps to avoid misleading CPU information ...eg A simple sys calendar table used in a high CPU query has very high CPU hits.

Comment: On that  last part , how do I get a row count kind of logic inside a case statement. Eg. `Select tablename , case when tablename like '%bigtb%' then  sel count ( '1' ) from  databasename.tablename  else 'dropped' end`. This is definitely not something that's going to work.... but it's just the bare bones logic that would go inside the above  kind of query. I wondered how should I go about doing that. Thank you very much again

Comment: *A simple sys calendar table* can be the cause of high CPU usage, depending on the actual query (I've seen very stupid things on calendars). So don't care about individual tables, check for individual queries causing high resource usage.